# Adding onChange event to existing field

Tags: reactjs

Using ReactJS I have a page with a bunch of fields. They don't have onChange events yet because when creating the fields, I don't know what they are. But after all are created, I need to go back and add onChange or other events to them. How do I do this?

So I've created the field like this:

```
function CreateTextInput({ id, placeholder, defaultValue }) {
    return (
        <input
            type="text"
            name={id}
            placeholder={placeholder}
            defaultValue={defaultValue}
            //onChange={onChange}
        />
    );
}
```

Say I create a field calls "PhoneNumber"

Now I need a function to create an onChange event function and then it as an event to the above field.

Could you please help?

Answer (score 1):

```js
<input
type="text"
name={id}
placeholder={placeholder}
defaultValue={defaultValue}
onChange={handleChange}
        />
```

```js
  function handleChange(event) {
    console.log(event.target.value);
  }
```

`handleChange` is the function that will be called whenever the input value changes. You can define `handleChange` as needed to handle the input change event in your application logic.

Later on, as you continue, you will probably use `useState`

```
  const [firstName, setFirstName] = useState('');
  
return (
    <input value={firstName}   name="firstName" onChange={e => setFirstName(e.target.value)} />
  );
```